# Directory names with a dot (.) in macOS

Tags: finder

I have a problem with folder naming in macOS — I need to name a folder with *.Menu in the end. But if I do that Finder thinks it's some sort of a system file and not a directory. The same goes with *.framework. Is there some setting in Finder to turn off this behaviour?

Comment: I would advise against using extensions that are used by the system for purpose other they what they are already registered for, for the system, as this may cause unwanted problems. I'd choose a different naming convention!

Comment: You could use ._Menu for example.  Should please both you and Mac maybe.

Comment: @john, nah, it doesn't look nice, but thanks for the idea :) Anyway, for now I decided to just make a whole hierarchy representing a namespace. It solves the problem, it's just I don't need a whole hierarchy for the moment. I think it's unfortunate that Apple decided to treat folders with special names as bundles. They should 've used zip archives with custom file extensions to represent .app, .framework and other system bundles.

Comment: Do mean * in the file name?

Comment: You could try a different file system manager.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to use an underscore. I wanted to have folders like:

`domainname.com
 domainname.cc`

to store local versions of websites I deploy.

But have settled with underscore instead. That means I don't have to worry about the mac thinking these folders are actually files of some specific type.  If I used .cc, there's a risk the mac would think that folder is a c++ source file :)  So, I'm happy with:

`domainname_com
 domainname_cc`

such that I know I don't have to worry about that.

Comment: The OP already stated in the comments he does not want to use an underscore.